# How do I suppress a specific error in php

Tags: php

I want to suppress the timeout error in a script that is running automatically. The fact that the script is timing out is not a problem since it will be running again in a minute after the timeout. I DO want all other errors reported.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function suppress_timeout() {
   if (connection_status() == CONNECTION_TIMEOUT) {
      // do your own thing here
   }
}

register_shutdown_function("suppress_timeout");
```

Answer (score 3):

In case [@nikic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422411/how-do-i-suppress-a-specific-error-in-php/3422416#3422416) is not what you are after, you can use

- [`set_error_handler`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) — Sets a user-defined error handler function

to setup a custom error handler that can handle the particular error.

Answer (score 2):

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

This will simply remove the timeout. Maybe that's enough?

Comment: I actually just set the timeout, so the cron jobs wouldn't overlap if there was more data than they could handle. I just don't want this to throw an error, since it's not